# Can Execute Procedure But Job That Runs Procedure Errors?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a procedure that pulls data from my database and uses MSDB.DBO.sp_send_dbmail to send out e-mails.  The procedure itself runs without a hitch when I use 'EXEC myprocedure'.  But when I set up a job for the procedure, the job fails with the following error

> 'Error formating query, probably invalid parameters [SQLState
>   42000](Error 22050).  The step failed'

There is one step in the job with the TSQL statement 'EXEC myprocedure', using the database that my procedure is stored on.  Does anyone know what could be causing this error?

**Update**

I've narrowed the problem down. It's something with the Exchange server I use. I was using a domain address (ie. mail.mycompany.com) as the 'Server name' under Database Mail's account configuration wizard. I was unable to send e-mails to listservs and external users using this domain address. I talked to our Exchange guy and he recommended using the actual IP address of one of the mail servers (ie. 10.123.53.53). That fixed the problem with listservs and external users, but now I am unable to send e-mails when I run my procedure using a job (the procedure itself executes properly when I manually run it). Does anyone know what criteria on our Exchange server I will need to change to fix this?

Comment: I am wondering if this error message is misleading? If somethIng works manually but not through server agent it is almost always permissions. Assuming you are in a dev environment, could you try running the job under your credentials (you can't use a proxy for TSQL step, so change Server Agent to run under your account). Just to eliminate any chance of it being security related? failing that, start a trace and watch exactly what is being executed.

Comment: Can you show the command you use to execute sp_send_dbmail?

Comment: @Pete Carter, I think you are right about the permissions issue.  I was able to run the job a couple of days.  Some of our SQL Server authenication was changed yesterday and the job hasn't run since.  I restored my DB From last week and created a job with the old version of the procedure (which ran last week in a job).  I received the same error.  I had initially thought it was changes I made to the code, but it looks like it's authentication related.  Do you know what the permissions issue might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the @query parameter used by sp_send_dbmail.  For some reason, my SQL Server Agent account (which was a domain administrator) was denied access to use sp_send_dbmail with the @query parameter.  I ended up dropping the @query parameter altogether and putting everything in the @body parameter.  The @body parameter became a concatenation of regular text and what returned from a SELECT query.

Answer (score 0):

This is like to be a permissions issue. It is impossible from the information given to specify exactly what permission is the problem, but a TSQL job step will run under the context of the Server Agent Service Account, so ensure that that account has SELECT permissions to the tables that are being used to build the query, and then make sure that it has permissions to the profile that you are using within Database Mail.